# iMac freezes and then "soft" restarts/ resets

Tags: imac, crash, performance, adobe-photoshop

This could be a general problem, but I couldn't find my exact issue and no solution so far.

I have an iMac 5k 27" 2019, 3GHz i5, 40GB RAM, Radeon 570X, macOS Monterey Version 12.3.1

In the last two weeks I have experienced this problem multiple times.
Out of nowhere my Mac freezes, no input or anything possible. Screen stays as it is. Then after some minutes it turns black and is immediately at the login. When I login again it looks like it restarted because everything is closed and my start up apps open up.
Although it doesn't feel like a restart, because the process between blackscreen and login screen is too fast.

I have no error code or notification from macOS.

I'm not 100% sure but if I remember correctly this always happened when I had lots of stuff open (a lot of chrome tabs, Visual Studio Code, Spotify, Outlook, Project Management Software, Calendar, Photoshop).
So far Photoshop was open every time this happened. I haven't used it a lot in the past month and every time it was open the crash happened. Photoshop is on the latest version.

Any ideas what could cause this?

I just wanted to do a restart and closed all apps, then I found a log behind all screens (that didn't show up directly after the restart so I overlooked it). I'm also not sure if this is the correct log, yesterday happened a crash. But the log seems like it's from 27.04 and I'm not sure if I had a crash there.

Maybe this helps, I hope there is no sensitive data in it, I couldn't find any.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               WindowServer [168]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Identifier:            WindowServer
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               88

Date/Time:             2022-04-27 15:18:40.6412 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 12.3.1 (21E258)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        83B8FE44-2344-86EB-6130-2C2E723AEEF5


Time Awake Since Boot: 1200000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace WATCHDOG, Code 2 
checkin with service: WindowServer returned not alive with context:
unresponsive dispatch queue(s): com.apple.WindowServer.HIDEvents
40 seconds since last successful checkin, 120611 total successsful checkins since load (0 induced crashes)
checkin with service: WindowServer returned not alive with context:
unresponsive dispatch queue(s): com.apple.WindowServer.HIDEvents
40 seconds since last successful checkin, 120611 total successsful checkins since load (0 induced crashes)

Application Specific Information:
StartTime:2022-04-13 16:14:22
GPU:AMD
MetalDevice for accelerator(0x9007): 0x7f9db1a59188 (MTLDevice: 0x7f9db80a0000)
IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/GFX0@0/ATY,Florin@0/AMDFramebufferVIB
IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/GFX0@0/ATY,Florin@2/AMDFramebufferVIB
boot-args:


Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Fault hit memory shortage
VM - Fault hit memory shortage
VM - Fault hit memory shortage


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b57197a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b571ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   SkyLight                            0x7ff8108245f5 CGXRunOneServicesPass + 762
3   SkyLight                            0x7ff810825739 server_loop + 91
4   SkyLight                            0x7ff81082542f SLXServer + 1690
5   WindowServer                           0x100e8e3a8 0x100e8b000 + 13224
6   dyld                                   0x10494f51e start + 462

Thread 1:: com.apple.coreanimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b57197a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b571ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   QuartzCore                          0x7ff812747e2d CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 534
3   QuartzCore                          0x7ff812747c02 thread_fun(void*) + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5ae4e1 _pthread_start + 125
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f6b thread_start + 15

Thread 2:: IOHIDService - RunLoopCompatibilityThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b57197a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b571ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80b674cdd __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 319
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80b673368 __CFRunLoopRun + 1276
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80b6727ac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 562
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80b6fa82b CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   IOKit                               0x7ff80df9bc8d __IOHIDServiceRunLoopCompatibilityThread + 306
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5ae4e1 _pthread_start + 125
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f6b thread_start + 15

Thread 3::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.VirtualDisplayListener
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b57197a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b571ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b579f7f mach_msg_server_once + 279
3   CoreDisplay                         0x7ff80c922cd0 -[VirtualDisplayListener rx] + 77
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f20cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f9317 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f9dfd _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b403eee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5aafd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f57 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b57197a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b571ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   CoreDisplay                         0x7ff80c9faa4f CoreDisplay::Mach::Server::Start() + 147
3   CoreDisplay                         0x7ff80c9fabb5 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (CoreDisplay::Mach::Server::*)(), CoreDisplay::Mach::Server*> >(void*) + 59
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5ae4e1 _pthread_start + 125
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f6b thread_start + 15

Thread 5::  Dispatch queue: IOHIDService(0x7f9d73d87370) id:0x10003af2a name:AppleMultitouchDevice
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b573bd2 __psynch_mutexwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5abe7e _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 76
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9cbb _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 205
3   IOKit                               0x7ff80dfa2a7e __IOHIDServiceQueueWillExecute + 36
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f918c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 277
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f9e30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 417
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3fb0f6 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 1987
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b403eee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5aafd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f57 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 6::  Dispatch queue: HID - IOService Enumeration
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b57197a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b571ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b4217d7 firehose_send_push_and_wait + 104
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b418e9c firehose_client_send_push_and_wait + 77
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b418884 firehose_buffer_tracepoint_reserve_wait_for_chunks_from_logd + 1170
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b416444 voucher_activity_trace_v_2 + 1315
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b41664b voucher_activity_trace_v + 20
7   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x7ff80b31f623 _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 7356
8   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x7ff80b31d93e _os_log + 128
9   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x7ff80b31d8b2 _os_log_impl + 21
10  IOKit                               0x7ff80dfc8055 _IOHIDEventSystemConnectionAddServices + 793
11  IOKit                               0x7ff80df994ad IOHIDNotificationSignalWithBlock + 44
12  IOKit                               0x7ff80df95257 __IOHIDEventSystemMatchNotifyFunction + 239
13  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80b63f076 __CFSetApplyFunction_block_invoke + 18
14  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80b63eee3 CFBasicHashApply + 115
15  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80b63ee33 CFSetApplyFunction + 131
16  IOKit                               0x7ff80df93fd8 __IOHIDEventSystemAddServices + 554
17  IOKit                               0x7ff80df92acc __IOHIDEventSystemServicePublished + 248
18  IOKit                               0x7ff80df4bd5f IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 179
19  IOKit                               0x7ff80df4bc9c _IODispatchCalloutWithDispatch + 33
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b40d89c dispatch_mig_server + 360
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f5d7c _dispatch_continuation_pop + 453
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b407208 _dispatch_source_invoke + 2179
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f91cd _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 342
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f9e30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 417
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3fb0f6 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 1987
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b403eee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5aafd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f57 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:: com.apple.windowserver.root_queue Dispatch queue: com.apple.WindowServer.HIDEvents
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b5730ea __ulock_wait + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3b06 _dlock_wait + 45
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b4163ca voucher_activity_trace_v_2 + 1193
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b41664b voucher_activity_trace_v + 20
4   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x7ff80b31f623 _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 7356
5   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x7ff80b31d93e _os_log + 128
6   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x7ff80b31d8b2 _os_log_impl + 21
7   MultitouchHID                       0x7ffa1960e650 MTTrackpadEventDispatcher::setScrollMomentumDispatchRate(float) + 244
8   MultitouchHID                       0x7ffa1961a586 MTTrackpadHIDManager::setPropertyInternal(_MTHIDPropertyType, void const*, bool) + 2422
9   MultitouchHID                       0x7ffa19615fbd MTSimpleHIDManager::setProperty(__CFString const*, void const*, bool) + 143
10  MultitouchHID                       0x7ffa19619c05 MTTrackpadHIDManager::setProperty(__CFString const*, void const*) + 123
11  MultitouchHID                       0x7ffa195f12ba MultitouchHIDClass::setProperty(__CFString const*, void const*) + 22
12  IOKit                               0x7ff80df9db52 _IOHIDServiceSetPropertyForClient + 1191
13  SkyLight                            0x7ff81057f862 EventTranslator::updateScrollMomentumDispatchRate(float, bool) + 176
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f20cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f9317 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f9e30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 417
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b402ac2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 343
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b4028a5 _dispatch_worker_thread + 234
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5ae4e1 _pthread_start + 125
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f6b thread_start + 15

Thread 9:: com.apple.windowserver.root_queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b5719ce semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3848 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3c75 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 58
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b4028ef _dispatch_worker_thread + 308
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5ae4e1 _pthread_start + 125
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f6b thread_start + 15

Thread 10:: com.apple.windowserver.root_queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b5719ce semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3848 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3c75 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 58
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b4028ef _dispatch_worker_thread + 308
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5ae4e1 _pthread_start + 125
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f6b thread_start + 15

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:: com.apple.windowserver.root_queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80b5719ce semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3848 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b3f3c75 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 58
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80b4028ef _dispatch_worker_thread + 308
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5ae4e1 _pthread_start + 125
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80b5a9f6b thread_start + 15


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000010004005  rbx: 0x0000000000008000  rcx: 0x00007ff7bf064308  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007ff7bf0643d0  rsi: 0x0000000003000902  rbp: 0x00007ff7bf064360  rsp: 0x00007ff7bf064308
   r8: 0x0000000000002703   r9: 0x0000000000000001  r10: 0x0000000000008000  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x0000000000002703  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000003000902
  rip: 0x00007ff80b57197a  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x00007ff70b90d7b0
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x0100001f 
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
    0x7ff80b570000 -     0x7ff80b5a7fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <26a59789-b846-3ed4-96dc-8dbef3c0c8e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7ff81055e000 -     0x7ff8108fbfff com.apple.SkyLight (1.600.0) <7511c8bd-d99a-322c-8256-5d81cdb9e2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/SkyLight
       0x100e8b000 -        0x100e8efff WindowServer (*) <c545cf4e-fef6-30f1-82a0-c480b60c3efa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
       0x10494a000 -        0x1049b5fff dyld (*) <dd9e80de-fb3b-349b-96a4-46874ad34d11> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7ff812701000 -     0x7ff812a10fff com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11) <ccb708de-75e3-3a64-81c8-f7c688b43d3b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7ff80b5a8000 -     0x7ff80b5b3fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <2f6c275d-7e14-3d31-a924-e1bb41d2415f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7ff80b5f5000 -     0x7ff80baf6fff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <743f0cb7-e962-3e42-8653-7bd141129561> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7ff80df47000 -     0x7ff80dffcfff com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2) <2cfad1ac-a8f3-3782-9c27-6f7b5caff101> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7ff80c911000 -     0x7ff80ca3cfff com.apple.CoreDisplay (265.2) <12835f73-f1ea-35bb-885b-dc8b4762a40d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/Versions/A/CoreDisplay
    0x7ff80b3f0000 -     0x7ff80b436fff libdispatch.dylib (*) <31d69d55-9895-326c-ad61-621c5ca87314> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7ff80b319000 -     0x7ff80b331fff libsystem_trace.dylib (*) <5437b3fc-51da-3f66-8c5c-31f7d5704c73> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7ffa195ef000 -     0x7ffa1963afff com.apple.iokit.plugin.MultitouchHID (5440.11) <29b06c0a-b8bb-3093-854f-115d1b8d276b> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleMultitouchDriver.kext/Contents/PlugIns/MultitouchHID.plugin/Contents/MacOS/MultitouchHID
```

It's not the full log, I can only paste 30.000 characters. Any better way to share the log? Pastebin?

Thanks @Tetsujin for your answer, unfortunately I don't have a drawing mode option in my performance settings of Photoshop.
[image: Photoshop Settings]

I only have one bootvolume but store files and everything on a NAS. It still has over 300GB free.
Photoshop can currently access 70% RAM (25GB), I try to reduce this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've known Photoshop to do this - somehow more of a forced logout than a true reboot.

Try going to Preferences > Performance, then on the right, Graphics Processor Settings & Advanced.

Reduce the Drawing Mode from Normal to Basic for starters [need to re-launch Ps each time you make a change before it will switch]. See if that helps. If not, gradually reduce the other settings one at a time until you get it.

[image]

Photoshop is notoriously poor at 'sharing' graphics with any other app, especially if it's using OpenGL. My Mac is an old Mac Pro, still on Mojave, so this may have changed on newer Macs since Apple abandoned OpenGL.

It may also be worth looking at how much overall RAM Ps is being allowed to use [left of the control panel, not in picture.] and also that you have enough Scratch Disk space - this is always better if you have it set to a non-boot drive, if you can… or at least de-prioritised so it's not first in the list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check that!

Comment: Welcome. I added some more things to test - refresh the page to see.

Comment: I will test the others, but I don't even have that option for `drawing mode` Really strange

Comment: What version of Photoshop? We're out of date here, staying on the same version, 2020 because we can't update the oldest Mac to anything newer. The options are still quite similar on an old Mac Pro &  brand new M1 iMac.

Comment: I'm on 23.3.1 According to Adobe Forum it seems like this options isn't available anymore because OpenGL isn't supported anymore and the graphics code was rewritten and this option doesn't apply there somehow. I still believe Photoshop is the problem here, but let's see maybe others have an idea what else I can try. Or maybe reducing the RAM for PS already did it. Time will tell